# dotnet CLI consoleloggerparameter

Tags: .net, command-line-interface, vscode-tasks

I noticed in my VS Code Task.json that I have a consoleloggerparameters argument for dotnet publish, but I have not been able to find a reference to it in the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) on it. Does anyone know where it is documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your link, it says:

> The dotnet publish command calls MSBuild, which invokes the Publish target.
> ...
> Any parameters passed to dotnet publish are passed to MSBuild.
>
> ...
>
> For more information, see the following resources:
>
> - MSBuild command-line reference

Which takes you to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022 which includes docs for this argument:

> `consoleLoggerParameters:parameters`
>
> Pass the parameters that you specify to the console logger, which displays build information in the console window. You can specify the following parameters:
>
> - PerformanceSummary. Show the time that's spent in tasks, targets, and  projects.
> - Summary. Show the error and warning summary at the end.
> - NoSummary. Don't show the error and warning summary at the end.
> - ErrorsOnly. Show only errors.
> - WarningsOnly. Show only warnings.
> - NoItemAndPropertyList. Don't show the list of items and properties that would appear at the start of each project build if the verbosity level is set to diagnostic.
> - ShowCommandLine. Show TaskCommandLineEvent messages.
> - ShowProjectFile. Show the path to the project file in diagnostic messages. This setting is on by default.
> - ShowTimestamp. Show the timestamp as a prefix to any message.
> - ShowEventId. Show the event ID for each started event, finished event, and message.
> - ForceNoAlign. Don't align the text to the size of the console buffer.
> - DisableConsoleColor. Use the default console colors for all logging messages.
> - DisableMPLogging. Disable the multiprocessor logging style of output when running in non-multiprocessor mode.
> - EnableMPLogging. Enable the multiprocessor logging style even when running in non-multiprocessor mode. This logging style is on by default.
> - ForceConsoleColor. Use ANSI console colors even if console does not support it.
> - Verbosity. Override the -verbosity setting for this logger.
>
> Use a semicolon to separate multiple parameters, as the following example shows:
>
> `-consoleloggerparameters:PerformanceSummary;NoSummary -verbosity:minimal`
>
> The default console logger is at normal verbosity and includes a Summary.

Comment: Thank you, my confusion about the msbuild was causing me confusion elsewhere. You're answer helped me with more than my question :)